# result of string concatenation is too long

Tags: sql, oracle, spool

Am using spooler to output a query 
those are the options am using

```
set timing off
set trims on
set trimo on
set linesize 10000
set wrap off
set pagesize 0
set heading on
set verify off
set feedback off
set sqlprompt
set flush off
set echo off
set time on
```

when using

```
select  X1|| CHR(9) ||  X2|| CHR(9) || ...
```

I keep getting `result of string concatenation is too long`
and when I used the `to_clob`

```
select  to_clob(X1) || CHR(9) ||  to_clob(X2) || CHR(9) || ...
```

the output line is not complete and it also takes too long
please note that I have 50 columns and about 80k row

what shall I do ?

Comment: It means the length of the concatenated string you are generating is exceeding the 4000 byte limit

Comment: Can you try adding `SET LONG 100000;` in the beginning before spooling?

Comment: @Crazy2crack still having same problem

Answer (score 0):

it was solved after adding those options

```
SET LONG  1000000
SET LONGC 1000000
```